# How can I query and compare the values of a JSONbField on an object?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model that contains a jsonbfield, and need to query the values of the dictionary. Within a query, I need to ensure that all the values of the dictionary are `None`, or that the entire field is None.

My model looks like:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    date_created=DatetimeField()
    json_dict = JSONField(default=dict, null=True)
```

Essentially I want to get something like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(json_dict={}) |Q(json_dict=None) | Q(all(v=None for v in json_dict.values())))
```

The most important part being the

```
Q(all(v=None for v in json_dict.values()))
```

But I cannot do that in a query. I was wondering if there was a way to check this while keeping the results in a queryset, rather than evaluating it into a list and checking there.

LIMITATIONS:

- I do not know the keys of the dictionary as they will be different for every object in MyModel.
- I must be able to use the `bulk_create` function, so overwriting save is not an option

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your best option, regarding the **performance**, is to create a new **calculated field** and filter by it:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    date_created=DatetimeField()
    json_dict = JSONField(default=dict, null=True)
    is_empty = BooleanField(default=True, editable=False) #<-calculated field.

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_empty = ( self.metadata is None or 
                          # self.json_dict=={} or ## other checks
                          all(v is None for v in self.json_dict.values()) )
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, your query is so easy, and, also, **index friendly**:

```
MyModel.objects.filter( is_empty = True )
```

More info at django [Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) docs.

Comment: Thanks for this answer I hadn't considered this before, but unfortunately I need to be able to use the `bulk_create` function on this model which does not use the save(), so this is not an option for me

Comment: @KathyRindhoops, Set is_empty value by hand on bulk_create

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) says you can ***only*** define a callable default value such as a `dict`. Having said that, I believe you should use `dict` as default and with that you can filter if the field is empty. Some like:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    json_dict = JSONField(default=dict)


MyModel.objects.filter(json_dict=dict())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was using that as an example but will update the question, however this does not answer the crux of the question which is about querying the values of the dictionary